# how to print this "*" pattern in a straight line..(JAVA) | In C this will be a staright * line

Tags: java

[image]

how to print this "*" pattern in a straight line..(JAVA) | In C this will be a staright * line..

Comment: Remove the ln from println.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    int n = 5;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

You need to use System.out.print() and not System.out.println() if you want them in same line